# How can I change the origin remote in VSCode?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

VS Code is my actual IDE and git client for all my projects. 
I'd like to change the origin remote of an actual repository.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

It can be done over the terminal. (VS code has a terminal)

1. Go to the root of the directory.
2. List your existing remotes in order to get the name of the remote you want to change.

   ```
   $ git remote -v
   origin  git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (fetch)
   origin  git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (push)
   ```
3. Change your remote's URL from SSH to HTTPS with the git remote set-url command.

   ```
   $ git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
   ```
4. Verify that the remote URL has changed.

   ```
   $ git remote -v
   origin  https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (fetch)
   origin  https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (push)
   ```

Comment: thanks, every things works fine with terminal but not with GUI Source Control menu! any thing to do?

Answer (score 16):

You can do it using GUI with the following steps

1. Click on Source Control on the sidebar and click on more actions

[image]

2. Go to Remote and use the options Add Remote and Remove Remote

[image]

Comment: Am I missing something, or is there no way to list all the remotes, and then edit a remote?

Comment: Ok but how do you select your remote?

Comment: I can't find a feature that lists remotes. But I installed an extension "Just Enough Git" which shows the "Remotes" section Inside the "Source Control" tab. Hope this helps.

Comment: @RoyM In the newest VSCode, there is a Remotes entry on the Activity Bar. Not sure if I had to install an extension to get this, but it allowed me to set the repo's GitHub remote.